# Magento 1.9 where is getSkipJsReloadPrice set?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, magic-getter

In `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php` the **getSkipJsReloadPrice** method is checked i want to change **getSkipJsReloadPrice** to return true where is that setting?

```
. ($this->getSkipJsReloadPrice() ? '' : ' onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()"')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the code in file : **app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Composite\Fieldset\Options.php**

`Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Composite_Fieldset_Options::getOptionHtml()`

```
public function getOptionHtml(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option $option)
{
    $renderer = $this->getOptionRender(
        $this->getGroupOfOption($option->getType())
    );
    if (is_null($renderer['renderer'])) {
        $renderer['renderer'] = $this->getLayout()->createBlock($renderer['block'])
            ->setTemplate($renderer['template'])
            ->setSkipJsReloadPrice(1); // Here is the code to set value
    }
    return $renderer['renderer']
        ->setProduct($this->getProduct())
        ->setOption($option)
        ->toHtml();
}
```